# How can I fix icon of python executable after using pyinstaller?

Tags: python, pycharm, pyinstaller

When I want to create an `exe` file using `pyinstaller` in IDE called `pycharm`. I have a problem to open `main.exe`
after I did these commands:
`pyinstaller --onefile --windowed --icon=savings.ico main.py`  or `pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed --icon=savings.ico main.py`  ,I can find that executable file really created on my directory folder `C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\PythonLesson\dist` but when I clicking on it `main.exe` nothing happens! But I see `main.exe` running behind the scenes in *Task Manager*. How can I make `main.exe` open immediately instead of just running behind the scenes in *Task Manager* (I can't see `main.exe` running on Desktop after clicking on it).
Maybe it depends on icon of exe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your `main.py` a script or a GUI application? If it's a script, then nothing will "show up" because there's nothing to show up. If you were expecting a terminal to show up, then don't use `--windowed`.

Comment: my exe is script , then what can I use instead of `--windowed`?

Comment: Don't use anything. Your script should just open into a terminal. If you want to prevent auto closing on exit, use `input('Done. Press Enter to close...')`

Comment: I have seen some exe based on terminal script that have icon and I want to make it too

Comment: I'm speaking from experience, just remove `--windowed`, keep `--icon=savings.ico`,  and you'll see for yourself the exe still has an icon.

Comment: Thanks , but when I move my exe , to another directory her icon disappears, can you please tell me how do I solve?

Comment: I think that's just a caching issue, try setting the distribution name to something else

Comment: still not working

Comment: Did you try `pyinstaller.exe main.py --onefile --icon=savings.ico --name=test`

Comment: Can you please explain to me what "--name = test" does?
I went another way, I needed to know how to clear cash of icons, I was helped by a command called ie4uinit -show

Comment: PyInstaller will output the compiled version of `main.py` to `test.exe` instead of `main.exe`

Comment: Thanks you very much!